# Adobe Reader download timeout (FTP & HTTP)

Tags: ftp, download, adobe-reader, timeout

The following downloads are timing out on 3 different machines on our network:

- ftp://ftp.adobe.com/pub/adobe/reader/win/10.x/10.1.0/en_US/AdbeRdr1010_en_US.msi
- ftp://ftp.adobe.com/pub/adobe/reader/win/10.x/10.1.0/en_US/AdbeRdr1010_en_US.exe
- http://ardownload.adobe.com/pub/adobe/acrobat/win/10.x/10.0.0/misc/CustWiz1000_en_US.exe

The parent pages display fine in the browser, and we can connect to other non-Adobe FTP locations without issue.

I can ping ftp.adobe.com fine, and I receive replies from 192.150.8.30

I can connect to **ftp.adobe.com** in Filezilla, and browse to /pub/adobe/reader/win/10.x/10.1.0/en_US, but any attempt to download the .exe or .msi produces a "connection timed out" error in Filezilla.  This occurs in both active and passive mode.

Orbit Downloader also times out.

I am based in Perth, Western Australia, and have been able to download files from ftp.adobe.com on my home machine.

We are connected to a WAN provided by [Telstra](http://www.telstra.com), and they have a firewall policy.  I will contact them now.

**Update**: it has to be a WAN firewall issue, as Telstra themselves are able to access the files fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Telstra confirmed it was a setup issue on their WAN firewall.  Working now.